# Sending BufferedImages Over Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, arrays, bufferedimage

I want to send a buffered image across the network as part of my custom class.

I currently just writeObject and readObject to get my class.

To send the image im currently doing:

`((DataBufferByte) i.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();`

How do i convert that back in to a BufferedImage?

Is there a better way to be doing this?

The class i send looks like:

```
public class imagePack{

public byte[] imageBytes;
public String clientName;
public imagePack(String name, BufferedImage i){
    imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) i.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    clientName = name;
}

    public BufferedImage getImage(){
     //Do something to return it}

}
```

Thanks again

Comment: *"To send the image im currently doing:"* That is an inefficient way to transmit images.  Encode it to PNG or JPG 1st.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705385/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-a-bufferedimage-in-java

Comment: I agree @Cratylus but that seems unefficent there to/

Comment: @LmC:I think the OP problem is how to convert the `DataBufferByte` to `BufferedImage`. The api gives the `byte[]` so the problem is how to convert the `byte[]` to `BufferedImage` which has an answer in the other SO thread.I added this for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert that back in to a BufferedImage, you must also know its width, height and type.

```
class imagePack {

    public byte[] imageBytes;
    public int width, height, imageType;
    public String clientName;

    public imagePack(String name, BufferedImage i) {
        imageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) i.getData().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        width = i.getWidth();
        height = i.getHeight();
        imageType = i.getType();
        clientName = name;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        if (imageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert.");
        BufferedImage i2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);
        byte[] newImageBytes = ((DataBufferByte) i2.getData()
                .getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(imageBytes, 0, newImageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        return i2;
    }
}
```