# Convert byte array of data type TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR to BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have a byte array with type TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR, and I know its width and height, I want to change it to BufferedImage, any ideas?

Comment: Is your byte array an image file, or is it just pixel data? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705385/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-a-bufferedimage-in-java (possible duplicate)

Comment: It's just pixed data. will make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be very efficient, but a `BufferedImage` can be converted to another type this way:

```
public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage image, int type) {
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), type);
    Graphics2D graphics = newImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    graphics.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

About the method you want to be implemented, you would have to know the width or height of the image to convert a `byte[]` to a `BufferedImage`.

Edit:
One way is converting the `byte[]` to `int[]` (data type `TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and using `setRGB`:

```
int[] dst = new int[width * height];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dst.length; i++) {
    int a = src[j++] & 0xff;
    int b = src[j++] & 0xff;
    int g = src[j++] & 0xff;
    int r = src[j++] & 0xff;
    dst[i] = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, dst, 0, width);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however what I want is creating a BufferedImage from byte array with type XXX, not from existing image, I update my question to make it clear, could you please help?

Comment: @July I answered that too, it's impossible unless you know the width or height. Why the downvote? Edit: I see you changed the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, maybe another guy did that? I edit the question to make it clear, sorry for the misleading before if it did.

Comment: Thanks again, will try your edited answer later and get back.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to create a `BufferedImage` from a byte array in `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` form, is to wrap the array in a `DataBufferByte` and create an interleaved `WritableRaster` from that. This will make sure there are no additional byte array allocations. Then create the `BufferedImage` from the raster, and a matching color model:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width = 300;
    int height = 200;

    int samplesPerPixel = 4; // This is the *4BYTE* in TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR
    int[] bandOffsets = {3, 2, 1, 0}; // This is the order (ABGR) part in TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

    byte[] abgrPixelData = new byte[width * height * samplesPerPixel];

    DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(abgrPixelData, abgrPixelData.length);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(buffer, width, height, samplesPerPixel * width, samplesPerPixel, bandOffsets, null);

    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    System.out.println("image: " + image); // Should print: image: BufferedImage@<hash>: type = 6 ...
}
```

Note however, that this image will be "unmanaged" (some HW accelerations will be disabled), because you have direct access to the pixel array.

To avoid this, create the `WritableRaster` without the pixels, and copy the pixels into it. This will use twice as much memory, but will keep the image "managed" and thus possible better display performance:

```
// Skip creating the data buffer
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, samplesPerPixel * width, samplesPerPixel, bandOffsets, null);
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, abgrPixelData);
// ...rest of code as above.
```

You could even do this (which might be more familiar):

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, abgrPixelData);
```