# DirectBuffer to Speed up ImageIO

Tags: java, nio, bufferedimage

I have a lot of operations involving generating a BufferedImage object using a third-party library and saving it to a jpg file. Sometimes one processing can have over 10,000 such savings. Currently I'm using `ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file)` directly but the performance is not very satisfactory.

I'm wondering if I can use direct ByteBuffer to make disk writing faster? I'm thinking about putting the BufferedImage into a direct ByteBuffer and finally save to disk using a FileChannel. I didn't find a way to do so. I wonder how can I put a BufferedImage to direct ByteBuffer? Some example code would help a lot.

Comment: Do you need to store the images as JPEG? If so, your best bet is probably using [native bindings for libJPEGTurbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/tree/master/java). It's possible to use nio-backed `ImageOutputStream`s, but I've yet to see substantial gains from this. However, if you just want to dump the pixels from memory with no file format, using a direct buffer may work. Here's some [sample code, using memory mapped `BufferedImage`s](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java).

Comment: Other things you might do to improve performance regarding ImageIO, is to disable disk caching (`ImageIO.setUseCache(false)`). But I doubt this will help much if you write to a file anyway.

Comment: @haraldK Yes, I'll need to write the the image to jpg file in the end. How does disk caching help?

Comment: Disk caching *does not help* (for performance that is, it *does* help in saving memory). But it's enabled by default. I'm suggesting you disable it.

Comment: JAI ImageIO has support for [nio `FileChannel`-backed `ImageOuputStream`s](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jaiimageio/stream/FileChannelImageOutputStream.java), you may want to try to see if that helps. But still, I think libJPEGTurbo is faster, as mentioned above.

Comment: @haraldK So is there a way to encode the bytebuffer to jpg and save it as jpg image? The save might still be faster since it's directly mapped to memory.

Comment: I think you are looking at this the wrong way. Memory mapped files are not going to be faster than memory. And your `BufferedImage`s are already in memory. If you do some profiling, most likely you will find that the time is spent in the JPEG encoding process, not writing the result to disk (assuming a decent SSD). Yes, you could probably make disk writing a little faster. But the real gain is switching to a faster encoder.

Answer (score -2):

```
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;

public byte[] toByteArray(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(baos);
    encoder.encode(image);            
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479683/4008428) answer try this. Should be faster.

Comment: I managed to do it as well, but later I found that the `byte[]` cannot be saved as jpg file.

Comment: *A Java program that directly calls into sun.\* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.* Read more in [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).